# split a comma separated string in a pair of 2 using php

Tags: php, function, loops, for-loop, explode

I have a string having 128 values in the form of :

```
1,4,5,6,0,0,1,0,0,5,6,...1,2,3.
```

I want to pair in the form of :

```
(1,4),(5,6),(7,8)
```

so that I can make a for loop for 64 data using PHP.

Comment: explode on coma. foreach() loop and build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = 'val1,val2,val3,val4';

function x($value)
    {
        $buffer = explode(',', $value);
        $result = array();

        while(count($buffer))
            { $result[] = array(array_shift($buffer), array_shift($buffer)); }

        return $result;
    }

$result = x($a);

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Shows:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "val1" [1]=> string(4) "val2" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "val3" [1]=> string(4) "val4" } }
```

If modify it, then it might help you this way:

```
<?php
$a = '1,2,3,4';

function x($value)
    {
        $buffer = explode(',', $value);
        $result = array();

        while(count($buffer))
            { $result[] = sprintf('(%d,%d)', array_shift($buffer), array_shift($buffer)); }

        return implode(',', $result);
    }

$result = x($a);

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Which shows:

```
string(11) "(1,2),(3,4)"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this in these steps:

1. Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to turn the string into an array of numbers
2. Use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk) to form groups of two
3. Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) to turn each group into a string with brackets
4. Use [`join()`](http://php.net/join) to glue everything back together.

You can use this delicious one-liner, because everyone loves those:

```
echo join(',', array_map(function($chunk) {
    return sprintf('(%d,%d)', $chunk[0], isset($chunk[1]) ? $chunk[1] : '0');
}, array_chunk(explode(',', $array), 2)));
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WgVtZp)

If the last chunk is smaller than two items, it will use `'0'` as the second value.

Comment: for odd values we would receive : (1,2),(3,4),
and the last value gets removed.
In my code,I am making loop using for and concatenating with comma.

Comment: @TusharKanti you mentioned there are 128 values, that's not an odd number.

Comment: ok my fault for it.sorry but That I just gave it as an example.The function should should work irrespective of how many values is there in the string and return in pair format.

Comment: Also,I am getting this Warning error on Wamp Client server :

Warning: vsprintf(): Too few arguments in C:\wamp\www\test\explode\test.php on line 12

Comment: @TusharKanti so the last item should be ignored if the list has an odd number of items?

Comment: The values may be required so,It can't be removed in my case.But anyways Its a good logic and code.

Comment: It should return :
(1,2),(3,0)..in place of (1,2),3